# Can I import data to Cloud Firestore without having to have exported first?

Tags: firebase, import, google-cloud-firestore

I want to populate my database with a lot of data and I have found there exists an import command but you should have exported first. I don't know if I can do it just with several json files of my collections and use the import command in order to make the population faster or the most efficient way to do it is just with batch writes?

I have reviewed the documentation and I have not found something similar but I wanted to be completely sure that I am not ruling out a very good option, Thank you for your time.

In nutshell I wonder if I can adapt my data in a specific format to be able to use the import command and load my data quickly without having to use batched writes. On the documentation I've found I can use import command if I previously exported but that is impossible for me because I still don't have any data in my database.

Comment: Are you asking of the file format that Firestore uses for its imports and exports is documented anywhere? If so, I recommend using that exact phrasing, as right now it wasn't clear to me, which may also be why somebody had downvoted your question before I got to it.

Comment: Yees I have already used export command to know the file format and try to replicate that format in some way to be able to use import. Nevertheless, the format that is created when using the export is quite complex with binary files.

Comment: I get that, and that probably explains why it isn't documented. I expect the files contents to essentially be the protobuffs/grpc binary representation of the document data. But y comment was that you should probably clarify your question on what you're looking for, as that makes it more likely somebody who knows for sure can answer it.

Comment: Thank you so much @FrankvanPuffelen for your prompt reply and suggestion I've edited the question, I hope my doubt is more understandable :)